# How do I delete a previous Windows partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, disk-management

I had previously installed Windows 7 on my `D:` partition. I don't know why('twas a long time ago) I re-installed it on my (currently) `C:` partition. But I use the one on my `"C:"` drive. I want to format the one on `D:` I'm unable to do it. Have tried it thru *Disk Management* & *EaseUS Partition Manager*, still can't format it. I checked `msconfig` and it shows that I boot from my current `C:` partition. I have no clue what to do. I'm kinda new to this so please help me sort it out. I tried googling my problem but am unable to find the right solution.

This is what Disk Management says about both:

```
D: Healthy(System, Page File, Active, Primary Partition)
C: Healthy(Boot, Crash Dump, Logical Drive)
```

Please help!

Comment: You can't delete `D` because `D` is the partition your operating system is installed on. I don't care what `msconfig` says what Disk Management is saing is that `D` is an Active Primary System Partition. `C` is only bootable more then like because its your boot partition and thats all.

Comment: So I can't ever delete D ? Is there anyway to make my C drive the Active Primary System Partition?

Comment: I never said you can't delete `D` I just said `D` is your system disk currently and if you DO delete it then your delete the installed operating system.  You could try and merge the two paritions but that doesn't give you an "extra" space.  Be sure to backup your personal files before you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C: Has your boot loader on it, which appears to boot from D. Which would mean your D drive is the one you are using. Do you just want to change the drive letters, or free up the extra space?

If you want to free the space up, it looks like you might need to use a disk imager program to clone your current Windows partition, format the entire drive, and restore that partition. You would need a Windows recovery disk to restore the boot loader.

So, yes, it is possible.

Comment: Well, I don't have a Windows Recovery disc with me right now. Is there any other way I could clone that partition?

Comment: Norton Ghost is something i used to use all the time at work. I'm sure there are free options available as well if you search. A disk imaging program is what you are looking for. One that can restore to a different sized destination.